# Python Scrape - loop page new url update list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to best figure how to word this.

I'm writing a script at the moment which i want it to check the website, look for new urls being added in the adverts, and add these new urls to the list (only if they are new)

However bit of a roadblock now.  I have created it so it builds a list of url's from the various iframes which is great - but i dont know how to get it so it reloads and keeps checking over the list for new links.

I think my question is - How would i loop the request to reload the website to check the list of urls and update the list if there is a new url found?

i've included my code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib.request as urllib2
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"


#selenium requests
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

#browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe') #home
url = "https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xa179248e50ce5afb507fd8c54e08a66fbac7b6ff"
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2) 

allLinks = []
allAdLinks = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="lxml") 
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
pageAdIframes = soup.find_all("iframe")
for iframe in pageAdIframes:
        source = iframe.get("src")
        if source:
            adLinks = "https:" + source
            allLinks.append(adLinks)
        else:
            continue
print(allLinks)

substring = "charts"

allLinksNew = [item for item in allLinks if substring not in item]

for link in allLinksNew:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    iframe_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="lxml")
    PooAdDivs = iframe_soup.find("div", "cell")
    for a in PooAdDivs.find_all('a', href=True):
    #PooAddLinks = PooAdDivs.find('a')
        PooAdlinks = a['href']
        allAdLinks.append(PooAdlinks)
print(allAdLinks)
```

***EDIT***

I've got the loop working so it updates the array with new links as it refreshes - however its updating with ALL links, not just new links.

I've put together this piece of code in the hope it would "if matches regex then ignore, otherwise append to the list"  But it doesnt seem to be working.  What would i be missing here?  Thanks!

```
    for link in allLinksNew:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        iframe_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="lxml")
        PooAdDivs = iframe_soup.find("div", "cell")
        for a in PooAdDivs.find_all('a', href=True):
        #PooAddLinks = PooAdDivs.find('a')
            PooAdlink = a['href']
            if re.findall(r'\d.{6}$', PooAdlink) in allAdLinks:
                continue
            else:
                allAdLinks.append(PooAdlink)
```

Comment: Basically a while loop and driver.refresh() then get all the urls and then check.

Comment: I had heard others say this on a google but unsure how i would go about implimenting it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the links in a set. Adding all the found links will actually add only the new links there.

Comment: I've tried this but due to some changes in the link eg: 'https://click.a-ads.com/1602827/169408/' and 'https://click.a-ads.com/1604350/169408/' the set recognises these as different yet they are for the same ad - is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: I'm not sure we can see the links you wrote in a comment